# Testing: how to focus on behavior instead of implementation without losing speed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

It seems, that there are two totally different approaches to testing, and I would like to cite both of them.

The thing is, that those opinions were stated 5 years ago (2007), and I am interested, what has changed since then and which way should I go.

[Brandon Keepers](http://opensoul.org/blog/archives/2007/06/20/rspec-is-getting-too-intimate-with-my-code/):

> The theory is that tests are supposed to be agnostic of the
>   implementation. This leads to less brittle tests and actually tests
>   the outcome (or behavior).
>
> With RSpec, I feel like the common approach of completely mocking your
>   models to test your controllers ends up forcing you to look too much
>   into the implementation of your controller.
>
> This by itself is not too bad, but the problem is that it peers too
>   much into the controller to dictate how the model is used. Why does it
>   matter if my controller calls Thing.new? What if my controller decides
>   to take the Thing.create! and rescue route? What if my model has a
>   special initializer method, like Thing.build_with_foo? My spec for
>   behavior should not fail if I change the implementation.
>
> This problem gets even worse when you have nested resources and are
>   creating multiple models per controller. Some of my setup methods end
>   up being 15 or more lines long and VERY fragile.
>
> RSpec’s intention is to completely isolate your controller logic from
>   your models, which sounds good in theory, but almost runs against the
>   grain for an integrated stack like Rails. Especially if you practice
>   the skinny controller/fat model discipline, the amount of logic in the
>   controller becomes very small, and the setup becomes huge.
>
> So what’s a BDD-wannabe to do? Taking a step back, the behavior that I
>   really want to test is not that my controller calls Thing.new, but
>   that given parameters X, it creates a new thing and redirects to it.

David Chelimsky:

> It’s all about trade-offs.
>
> The fact that AR chooses inheritance rather than delegation puts us in
>   a testing bind – we have to be coupled to the database OR we have to
>   be more intimate with the implementation. We accept this design choice
>   because we reap benefits in expressiveness and DRY-ness.
>
> In grappling with the dilemma, I chose faster tests at the cost of
>   slightly more brittle. You’re choosing less brittle tests at the cost
>   of them running slightly slower. It’s a trade-off either way.
>
> In practice, I run the tests hundreds, if not thousands, of times a
>   day (I use autotest and take very granular steps) and I change whether
>   I use “new” or “create” almost never. Also due to granular steps, new
>   models that appear are quite volatile at first. The valid_thing_attrs
>   approach minimizes the pain from this a bit, but it still means that
>   every new required field means that I have to change
>   valid_thing_attrs.
>
> But if your approach is working for you in practice, then its good! In
>   fact, I’d strongly recommend that you publish a plugin with generators
>   that produce the examples the way you like them. I’m sure that a lot
>   of people would benefit from that.

[Ryan Bates](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=6528):

> Out of curiosity, how often do you use mocks in your tests/specs?
>   Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but I'm finding it severely
>   limiting. Since switching to rSpec over a month ago, I've been doing
>   what they recommend in the docs where the controller and view layers
>   do not hit the database at all and the models are completely mocked
>   out. This gives you a nice speed boost and makes some things easier,
>   but I'm finding the cons of doing this far outweigh the pros. Since
>   using mocks, my specs have turned into a maintenance nightmare. Specs
>   are meant to test the behavior, not the implementation. I don't care
>   if a method was called I just want to make sure the resulting output
>   is correct. Because mocking makes specs picky about the
>   implementation, it makes simple refactorings (that don't change the
>   behavior) impossible to do without having to constantly go back and
>   "fix" the specs. I'm very opinionated about what a spec/tests should
>   cover. A test should only break when the app breaks. This is one
>   reason why I hardly test the view layer because I find it too rigid.
>   It often leads to tests breaking without the app breaking when
>   changing little things in the view. I'm finding the same problem with
>   mocks. On top of all this, I just realized today that mocking/stubbing
>   a class method (sometimes) sticks around between specs. Specs should
>   be self contained and not influenced by other specs. This breaks that
>   rule and leads to tricky bugs. What have I learned from all this? Be
>   careful where you use mocking. Stubbing is not as bad, but still has
>   some of the same issues.
>
> I took the past few hours and removed nearly all mocks from my specs.
>   I also merged the controller and view specs into one using
>   "integrate_views" in the controller spec. I am also loading all
>   fixtures for each controller spec so there's some test data to fill
>   the views. The end result? My specs are shorter, simpler, more
>   consistent, less rigid, and they test the entire stack together
>   (model, view, controller) so no bugs can slip through the cracks. I'm
>   not saying this is the "right" way for everyone. If your project
>   requires a very strict spec case then it may not be for you, but in my
>   case this is worlds better than what I had before using mocks. I still
>   think stubbing is a good solution in a few spots so I'm still doing
>   that.

Comment: It is a good question; I have seen a lot of brittle unit tests as a result of all the mocking that is going on. JavaScript unit tests can be worse.

Comment: Man, I like all of these thoughts! The biggest problem here is probably Rails. In GOOS, they say you shouldn't mock third party code (which they would include ActiveRecord), because you can't make design changes which affect it. That's essentially the problem, David points out that he would rather use composition, but can't b/c AR chose inheritance (if he wants to do things as traditionally done in Rails). Personally, I have a lot of ideas, and I don't know which are right. Good question, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think all three opinions are still completely valid. Ryan and I were struggling with the maintainability of mocking, while David felt the maintenance tradeoff was worth it for the increase in speed.

But these tradeoffs are symptoms of a deeper problem, which David alluded to in 2007: ActiveRecord. The design of ActiveRecord encourages you to create god objects that do too much, know too much about the rest of the system, and have too much surface area. This leads to tests that have too much to test, know too much about the rest of the system, and are either too slow or brittle.

So what's the solution? Separate as much of your application from the framework as possible. Write lots of small classes that model your domain and don't inherit from anything. Each object should have limited surface area (no more than a few methods) and explicit dependencies passed in through the constructor.

With this approach, I've only been writing two types of tests: isolated unit tests, and full-stack system tests. In the isolation tests, I mock or stub everything that is not the object under test. These tests are insanely fast and often don't even require loading the whole Rails environment. The full stack tests exercise the whole system. They are painfully slow and give useless feedback when they fail. I write as few as necessary, but enough to give me confidence that all my well-tested objects integrate well.

Unfortunately, I can't point you to an example project that does this well (yet). I talk a little about it in my presentation on [Why Our Code Smells](http://opensoul.org/blog/archives/2012/05/23/why-our-code-smells), watch Corey Haines' presentation on [Fast Rails Tests](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNn6M2vqxHE), and I highly recommend reading [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/).

Comment: I still feel the tradeoff is worth it for the increased speed in controller specs, because we're stubbing/mocking a different layer. Even though `new` and `create` come from ActiveRecord, if they are called from controllers, they are effectively public APIs on _your_ model. I do _not_, however, think it's worth the tradeoffs in model specs because you have to stub lower level details of ActiveRecord.

Comment: I would generally agree with that. Although lately I rarely write controller specs because they usually are only a couple lines of code. If they get longer than that, then I pull the logic into another object that can be tested.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for compiling the quotes from 2007. It is fun to look back.

My current testing approach is covered in [this RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test) which I have been quite happy with. In summary I have two levels of tests.

- **High level:** I use request specs in RSpec, Capybara, and VCR. Tests can be flagged to execute JavaScript as necessary. Mocking is avoided here because the goal is to test the entire stack. Each controller action is tested at least once, maybe a few times.
- **Low level:** This is where all complex logic is tested - primarily models and helpers. I avoid mocking here as well. The tests hit the database or surrounding objects when necessary.

Notice there are no controller or view specs. I feel these are adequately covered in request specs.

Since there is little mocking, how do I keep the tests fast? Here are some tips.

- Avoid excessive branching logic in the high level tests. Any complex logic should be moved to the lower level.
- When generating records (such as with Factory Girl), use `build` first and only switch to `create` when necessary.
- Use [Guard](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard) with [Spork](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork) to skip the Rails startup time. The relevant tests are often done within a few seconds after saving the file. Use a `:focus` tag in RSpec to limit which tests run when working on a specific area. If it's a large test suite, set `all_after_pass: false, all_on_start: false` in the Guardfile to only run them all when needed.
- I use multiple assertions per test. Executing the same setup code for each assertion will greatly increase the test time. RSpec will print out the line that failed so it is easy to locate it.

I find mocking adds brittleness to the tests which is why I avoid it. True, it can be great as an aid for OO design, but in the structure of a Rails app this doesn't feel as effective. Instead I rely heavily on refactoring and let the code itself tell me how the design should go.

This approach works best on small-medium size Rails applications without extensive, complex domain logic.

Answer (score 8):

Great questions and great discussion.  @ryanb and @bkeepers mention that they only write two types of tests.  I take a similar approach, but have a third type of test:

- Unit tests: isolated tests, typically, but not always, against plain ruby objects.  My unit tests don't involve the DB, 3rd party API calls, or any other external stuff.
- Integration tests: these are still focused on testing one class; the differences is that they integrate that class with the external stuff I avoid in my unit tests.  My models will often have both unit tests and integration tests, where the unit tests focus in the pure logic that can be tested w/o involving the DB, and the integration tests will involve the DB.  In addition, I tend to test 3rd party API wrappers with integration tests, using VCR to keep the tests fast and deterministic, but letting my CI builds make the HTTP requests for real (to catch any API changes).
- Acceptance tests: end-to-end tests, for an entire feature. This isn't just about UI testing via capybara; I do the same in my gems, which may not have an HTML UI at all.  In those cases, this exercises whatever the gem does end-to-end.  I also tend to use VCR in these tests (if they make external HTTP requests), and like in my integration tests, my CI build is setup to make the HTTP requests for real.

As far as mocking goes, I don't have a "one size fits all" approach.  I've definitely overmocked in the past, but I still find it to be a very useful technique, especially when using something like [rspec-fire](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire).  In general, I mock collaborators playing roles freely (particularly if I own them, and they are service objects) and try to avoid it in most other cases.

Probably the biggest change to my testing over the last year or so has been inspired by [DAS](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/): whereas I used to have a `spec_helper.rb` that loads the entire environment, now I explicitly load just the class-under test (and any dependencies).  Besides the improved test speed (which does make a huge difference!) it helps me identify when my class-under-test is pulling in too many dependencies.